# Is it posisble to have rook ceph with zabbix

Tags: zabbix, ceph

I want to have my rook ceph cluster monitored by zabbix.
However, enabling module and configuring zabbix host is not enough.

Basically it expects that mon/mgr containers have zabbix_sender, which upstream rejected (https://github.com/ceph/ceph-container/issues/1651).

Before I will start building my own ceph images, does anybody have better idea?
Maybe somehow mount zabbix_sender from host? How this could be done that rook operator creates such containers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after several experiments, easiest solution is to extend ceph images in this way:

```
FROM quay.io/ceph/ceph:v16.2.6
RUN yum install -y https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/8/x86_64/zabbix-release-5.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm && yum install -y zabbix-sender && yum clean all
```